# What is the theory behind sets in programming languages?

Tags: set

What is known as Set Theory does not have much to do with "sets" as used in programming languages. In programming, one needs something like a pair: a predicate and, probably, a complete order, with an equivalence relation that only uses predicates.

Or there could be other approaches.

Is there a theory behind all this that programming languages model?

Comment: "Set Theory for Computer Science - University of Cambridge (PDF)" https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~gw104/STfCS2010.pdf

Answer (score 0):

CS is a mix-and-match of different  parts of the set theories ( there is more than one set theory) and the type theories (there’s also more than one).

The type theories and the set theories, as well as the category theory, are in a sense, competitors presenting different approaches to be a foundational theory of the math

CS is stillI, mostly the set theory, which, you are right, based on the predicate logic, for example, the formalization of automates / Turing machines is also all done in terms of the sets theory. From the bool logic we can go to unions, intersections, bijections etc

An alternative approach would be a type theory, where  "and" and "or" without the bool logic can be encoded as types in the type theory itself.

Comment: CS is not a set theory. Take lambda calculus. It took a lot of efforts to model it in sets, but it does not come from sets; same with turing machines and finite automata.
In any case, the question was about the "Set" "functor" in programming languages and what theory is behind it. Definitely not a set theory.